# Transparency became blue, Flash

Tags: flash, flash-cs4

My project has many layers with transparency, but suddenly they turned blue
Because of what it can and how can I fix it?
Reloading does not work

Comment: What were you doing when the transparent layers turned blue? You definitely need to show us the relevant parts of your code. Please read about making a [MCVE] of your problem

Comment: Blue might be a color of simple buttons with no graphics and hit area only.

Comment: @divibisan I think this is more of an IDE issue rather than code itself. Still they **could provide more useful info** than just one sentence.